# My function to generate PDFs from a Google Doc is not working

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am very new to Google Cloud Functions and I have pieced together information from various sources for my script but something is not working correctly. I am trying to create a function that uses a Google Doc as a template, uses a find-and-replace function to update values in the copy, then create a PDF that ends up in a Drive folder. I'm doing this so I can create large PDFs in a batch, rather than one-by-one which I'm currently doing with Google Apps Script.

When I try to deploy the function, I get this error:** Build failed: npm ERR! Cannot read property 'googleapis' of undefined**

However, I installed googleapis via the terminal, it is in the package.json file, and I can confirm via the terminal I have the most updated version (133). I've also shared the Drive folder and the Google Doc with the default service account. The entrypoint is generatedPdfFromTemplate

Here's the package.json file:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
     "googleapis": "^133.0.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the index.js file:

```
const fs = require('fs'); // Make sure you import fs at the beginning
const { google } = require('googleapis');

exports.generatePdfFromTemplate = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const fileId = req.body.templateId;
    const nameForNewFile = req.body.nameForNewFile || 'New Document';
    const outputFileName = `/tmp/${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.pdf`;
    const finds = req.body.finds;
    const replaces = req.body.replaces;

    const newFileId = await exports.copyDoc(fileId, nameForNewFile);
    await exports.findAndReplaceTextInDoc(newFileId, finds, replaces);
    await exports.convertDocToPDF(newFileId, outputFileName);

    // Respond back with success message or serve the PDF directly
    res.status(200).send('PDF generated successfully.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error generating PDF', err);
    res.status(500).send('Failed to generate PDF.');
  }
};

// Copy Google Doc
exports.copyDoc = async (fileId, nameForNewFile) => {
  try {
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] });
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

    const response = await drive.files.copy({
      fileId,
      fields: 'id'
    });

    if (response.status === 200) {
      const newFileId = response.data.id;
      if (nameForNewFile) {
        await drive.files.update({
          fileId: newFileId,
          resource: { name: nameForNewFile },
          fields: 'id'
        });
      }
      return newFileId;
    } else {
      throw new Error('Failed to copy document');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to copy doc', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

// Find and replace text in Google Doc
exports.findAndReplaceTextInDoc = async (documentId, finds, replaces) => {
  try {
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents'
      ]
    });
    const docs = google.docs({ version: 'v1', auth });

    let requests = finds.map((find, i) => ({
      replaceAllText: {
        containsText: { text: find, matchCase: true },
        replaceText: replaces[i],
      },
    }));

    const res = await docs.documents.batchUpdate({
      documentId,
      resource: { requests }
    });

    return res;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to replace text', err);
    throw err;
  }
};

// Upload PDF to a specific Google Drive folder
async function uploadPdfToDrive(fileName, folderId) {
  const auth = await google.auth.getClient({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'] });
  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  const fileMetadata = {
    name: fileName,
    parents: [folderId] // Specify the folder ID here
  };
  const media = {
    mimeType: 'application/pdf',
    body: fs.createReadStream(fileName)
  };
  const response = await drive.files.create({
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
  });
  return response.data.id;
}

// Convert a Google Doc to PDF
exports.convertDocToPDF = async (fileId, outputFileName, googleDriveFolderId) => {
  try {
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({ scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'] });
    const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

    const dest = fs.createWriteStream(outputFileName);
    await drive.files.export({
      fileId,
      mimeType: 'application/pdf'
    }, { responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(res => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        res.data
          .on('end', () => resolve(outputFileName))
          .on('error', err => reject(err))
          .pipe(dest);
      });
    });

    const uploadedFileId = await uploadPdfToDrive(outputFileName, googleDriveFolderId);

    // Cleanup: Delete the temporary PDF file after uploading
    fs.unlink(outputFileName, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Failed to delete the temporary file', err);
        throw err;
      }
      console.log('Temporary file deleted successfully');
    });

    return uploadedFileId;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Failed to convert doc to PDF', err);
    throw err; 
  }
};

(async () => {
  try {
    const fileId = 'TemplateIdHere'; 
    const googleDriveFolderId = 'DriveFolderIdHere';
    const nameForNewFile = 'New Document';
    // Ensure the output file is placed in the /tmp directory
    const outputFileName = `/tmp/${Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)}.pdf`;

    // Definitions for finds and replaces
    const finds = ['<NAME>', '<JOB>']; // Example placeholders
    const replaces = ['Samantha', 'Admin'];

    const newFileId = await exports.copyDoc(fileId, nameForNewFile);
    await exports.findAndReplaceTextInDoc(newFileId, finds, replaces);
    await exports.convertDocToPDF(newFileId, outputFileName, googleDriveFolderId);

    console.log('PDF generation and upload successful.');
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
  }
})();
```